# Contentful: Return entries in a random order

Tags: php, contentful

Is it possible to return entries in a random order through a Contentful Query?
 Without specifying a `"->where"` parameter, it will *sort the entries alphabetically*.

I've tried using `shuffle()` and `array_rand()`, however it doesn't recognise a `Contentful` object as an *array*.

Here's what I currently have:

```html
<?php   
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType(PRODUCT_TYPE);

$entries = $client->getEntries($q1->where('fields.images[exists]', 'true')->where('fields.category.sys.id', $entry->getCategory()->getId())->where('limit', '3'));

$array_shuffle = shuffle($entries)

foreach ($array_shuffle as $entry) 
  {}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Author of the Contentful PHP SDK here.

Unfortunately the class that holds the result from a query currently doesn't allow access to the internal array. I just opened a [pull request](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.php/pull/115) to change that. It will be part of version 1.2, to be released later this week.

In the meantime your best bet is to use `iterator_to_array()`.

```php
<?php           
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType(PRODUCT_TYPE);

$entries = $client->getEntries($q1->where('fields.images[exists]', 'true')->where('fields.category.sys.id', $entry->getCategory()->getId())->where('limit', '3'));

$arrEntries = iterator_to_array($entries);

shuffle($arrEntries)

foreach ($arrEntries as $entry) 
  {}
```

Note I also fixed how `shuffle()` is used. It doesn't return the shuffled array, it changes it in place.